# Alternating 1's and 0's in a table - Python

Tags: python, list, tabular

I want to make a table of alternating 1's and 0's using for statements and lists for a given number of rows and columns (similar to the code below). Any ideas as to how I would do this?

```
#fill elements in left and right columns with ones

ROWS = m
COLUMNS = n
table = []

for i in range(COLUMNS):
    if i ==0 or i == (COLUMNS-1):
        column = [1] * ROWS
    else:
        column = [0] * ROWS
    table.append(column)

for i in range(ROWS):
    for j in range(COLUMNS):
        print(table[j][i], end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: Can you paste a small snippet of what that table would ideally look like?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out a code where the 1's and 0's are alternating on each row AND column.

Comment: [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]  for a given number of columns and a given number of rows. In this example, it would be for one row and 8 columns.

Comment: @user3495872 And how would the result be for 2 rows and 8 columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
ROWS = 5
COLUMNS = 5
table = [[1 if i%2==0 else 0 for i in range(COLUMNS)] for j in range(ROWS)]

for row in table:
for cell in row:
    print (cell, end=' ')
print()
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1
```

OR maybe:

```
table = [[(i+j)%2 for i in range(COLUMNS)] for j in range(ROWS)]
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: @user3495872, Answer updated. Also, if my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? thank you.

Comment: +1 I like the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the first and the second rows separately and return the copies of them alternatively, like this

```
def get_table(rows, cols):
    row2,row1 = [i%2 for i in xrange(cols)],[i%2 for i in xrange(1,cols+1)]
    return [row1[:] if i % 2 else row2[:] for i in xrange(rows)]

print get_table(5, 6)
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

COLUMNS = 5; ROWS = 4
values = cycle([0, 1])
table = [list(islice(values, COLUMNS)) for _ in xrange(ROWS)]
# [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

This automatically cycles the values and avoiding making copies of existing lists.

Working with even length columns:

```
COLUMNS = 4; ROWS = 4
values = [cycle([0, 1])]
if COLUMNS % 2 == 0:
    values.append(cycle([1, 0]))
values = cycle(values)

table = [list(islice(next(values), COLUMNS)) for _ in xrange(ROWS)]
```

Comment: It's great (and twice as fast as other solutions). I forgot about `islice`, thanks!

Comment: but it doesn't work for even COLUMNS.

Comment: @m.wasowski ahh good spot - one sec :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `itertools.cycle` for more readable (faster?) code:

```
import itertools

rows = cols = 4
even_gen = itertools.cycle((0, 1))
odd_gen = itertools.cycle((1, 0))

even = [next(even_gen) for _ in xrange(cols)]
odd = [next(odd_gen) for _ in xrange(cols)]
both = itertools.cycle((even, odd))
result = [next(both)[:] for _ in xrange(rows)]
```

*EDIT* added `next(both)[:]` to actually return copy of row